# Should i use symfony or not

Tags: symfony-1.4

I want to make a lite facebook version using symfony 1.4. however i had some issues with symfony and memory in the past so :

is it wise to go with symfony ?
what are the server requirements to run it smoothly (cpu, memory ...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the memory it is more or less a question how you define "lite" ;) There are a ton of  successful websites using symfony 1.4 (also big ones like for example delicious.com), so I believe that the question of scalability is more about how mature your knowledge is for performance issues.

What are the alternative approaches you have in mind?  Writing your own framework? Then my strong advice is to use an existing one instead (does not have to be sf1.4 though), as most work to start implementing the actual application logic is already done for you.

Did you habe a look at Symfony2? As it is a much more modern framework that is quite stable now (as 2.1 with new forms component will be released soon) I would suggest using it ;)